# Is there a way to backup "drivers" the same way we do on PCs?

Tags: factory-reset, phoenix-os

I have a dual-booting Windows 10 tablet that has an Android side. I want to wipe it clean including the Windows side and fresh install PhoenixOS on it. I poked around PhoenixOS but the touch screen, accelerometer, WiFi, Bluetooth, and audio doesn't work on that device with it installed.

I was wondering if there's a way to backup drivers from the original Android installed so I can add it to PhoenixOS and make those features work again? I'm not that familiar with Android terms so all I know is how it's done on the PC.

Comment: Unlike PC's, OS's for tablets/phones are not universal. Usually they are distributed as a complete package for a certain device, called ROM which includes proprietary binary blobs (equivalent to PC's drivers) only for that particular device. You'll be able to flash PhoenixOS if the custom ROM is available for your device. Backing up drivers and restoring in another OS (ROM) is called porting in Android world, which isn't simple to achieve.

Comment: @IrfanLatif, thank you for the informative comment! Is the case going to be simpler if I'm transferring those binary blobs from an equivalent version Android? For example, my tablet came with Android 5.1 and similarly, PhoenixOS also has a version for Android 5.1

Comment: Yes but drivers isn't the only part that isn't universal. You also need a device specific kernel, device tree and accordingly created partition table.

Comment: I assume the kernel can't be copied from the original Android rom the PhoenixOS huh...

Comment: You can go through [this](https://www.lineageosrom.com/2017/01/how-to-build-lineageos-rom-for-any.html?m=1), focus on "Prepare the device-specific code" and "Extract proprietary blobs" to get a basic idea how ROMs are built. See [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-to-instal-windows-ios-linux-t3763961) for differences in OS's of PC and Android devices.